# Accessing subdomain while trying to keep entered URL in address bar and append filepath

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, prestashop-1.5

I have a Prestashop install in a folder (which also is a subdomain) on my server.

Currently Visitors visit `www.spine-design.co.uk`.

They are shown the data in `www.connive.co.uk/Spine` (also accessible via spine.connive.co.uk)

The address bar defaults to `www.connive.co.uk/Spine/(content)`

I'm after a way of having the address bar keep `www.spine-design.co.uk` whilst appending any further filepath to the end.

Ultimately I want to be able to change prestashop's URL & SEO settings so that all generated links/addresses show `www.spine-design.co.uk` as well. Currently it has to be set to `www.connive.co.uk/Spine` otherwise it just displays a white, blank screen when accessed.

I'm and experienced front-end designer/developer, delving into .htaccess and re-directs for what is essentially the first time.

I've tried various .htaccess rules, even used some generators and not had the result I'm after.

If I'm honest, I'm not even sure if .htaccess is the best route to go down to get what I require.

Comment: Show us your current .htaccess rules of `www.spine-design.co.uk`.

Comment: You can use multistore feature for that.

Comment: Thank you @user2831723 I was unaware of those features.